# remove paint from carving

Tags: paint-removal

the new place i just moved into has this gorgeous carving around the light fixture but as you can see the previous owners gave it the landlord special

[image]

i have no idea what the material is but i want to strip the paint so all the detail can be seen. how would I go about such a thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just replace it. Ceiling medallions can be cheap especially if you buy them at large online housewares retailers rather than designer architectural suppliers. Stripping all the paint out of the nooks and crannies will be very difficult at best, and if it is made from an absorbent material it will be impossible. Preparing this thing for repainting is possible, but stripping it back to its raw glory is not, especially since it is probably made of foam or plaster and was never glorious until painted.